# storing gender 'Male' and 'Female' as Enum type is good or not ? MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database, enums, normalization

I am looking for best way to store gender in MySQL Database, whether 'Enum' is the best for it or I should go for 'INT'?.
I want to store this in my user table what should be best ? storing gender as

```
Using Enum - 'Male' and 'Female' or 'male' and 'female' or 'M' and 'F' or 'm' and 'f'
```

or

```
Using INT - '1' and '2'
```

or

```
TINYINT(1) - '1' and '2'
```

or

```
bit/Boolean  IsFemale and IsMale
```

Comment: Whats wrong with TINYINT(1)?

Comment: You could also consider a bit/Boolean field such as IsFemale, as long as you consider that there can be only two genders!

Comment: ok but after using TINYINT i have to perform join

Comment: yes that's why i want to know best solution for it whether it should be TINYINT or bit/Boolean or Enum ?

Comment: i have edited my question as per your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

This is primarily opinion-based and there is no rule or anything (imo would be stupid anyway) like that. Use whatever you like. Your application just needs to know what to expect and has to make use of whatever value the database returns.